# Why MATLAB returns an error using `conv` function?

Tags: matlab

I'm using MATLAB 2015a. Even if I try to run document example of `conv` function, i get an error saying `Error using conv (line 15), Not enough input arguments.`.

This is the example code I'm using:

```
u = [1 0 1];
v = [2 7];
w = conv(u,v)
```

What is the problem with my MATLAB?

Comment: You've probably shadowed `conv` with your own variable or function. What does `which conv` return?

Comment: @excaza Oh, you're right. It is using another toolbox other than that of MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to find the documentation for that version online without a license. You can find the documentation for your version by typing

```
help conv
```

Presumably the interface changed after your version. So you have to see what your documentation says.

FWIW, the documentation archives are [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html), but I cannot access them.

Also, I tried your code in Matlab 2015b (that is, `b`, not `a`), and it worked. So it must have changed between those two versions.

According to  excaza, the docs haven't changed. So, like they say, it must be a shadowing issue. You would verify that by using `clear all` before your code snippet.

Comment: This is a shadowing issue. The inputs to `conv` haven't changed since at least R2006a.